# How do I select everything where two columns contain equal values in CQL?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying to select everything where two columns contain equal values.  Here is my CQL query:

```
select count(someColumn) from somekeySpace.sometable where columnX = columnY
```

This doesn't work.  How can I do this?

Comment: You can't do this. Cassandra don't support it.

Comment: So it's something that i need to do.  Does this mean that I will need to select everything from those columns and then do it outside of CQL in my application...like in my java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't query like that, cassandra don't support it**

You can do this in different way.
First you have to create a separate counter table.

```
CREATE TABLE match_counter(
    partition int PRIMARY KEY,
    count counter
);
```

At the time of insertion into your main table if `columnX = columnY` then increment the value here. Though you have only a single count, you can use a static value of partition

```
UPDATE match_counter SET count = count + 1 WHERE partition = 1;
```

Now you can get the count of match column

```
 SELECT * FROM match_counter WHERE partition = 1;
```

Comment: You're not using that separate table with the main table. Where are you comparing columns?

Comment: The comparison should be done from the programming language before executing insert into your main table.